# bash How to extract first match from n files efficiently

Tags: bash, grep

I have a large number of text files containing timestamped data for a day. Each file is a day. I want to extract a single line from each file that is the same time of day. The following works but is quite slow - is there a faster way?

```
for f in nGENERIC*.txt ;do egrep -m1 "*T1600*" $f ; done > a
```

Comment: You could also use `fgrep` for this, if you're only interested in a fixed string, and not a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `grep` should do...

```
 grep -m1 "T1600" nGENERIC*.txt > output
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same terms but how is this faster?

Comment: Remember the "-m1" flag I want the first instance of T1600 from each file. So I don't think this solution works

Comment: @ManinMoon : Edited with `-m1` flag

Comment: @iamauser The main time consumer wouldn't be instantiating grep (loop) but rather the amount of lines to parse, no?

Comment: Wow, the -m1 works as I want it. I thought it would only return a single line from the whole lot - but not so... And it is amazingly faster. Good solution. Thank you

Comment: @ManInMoon Did you also try this solution in combination with -F flag? Any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not really using any regex you will be better off using `-F` switch to avoid regex processing and make it little more efficient:

```
grep -F -m1 "T1600" nGENERIC*.txt > a
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try head?

```
 for f in nGENERIC*.txt ;do head -n1 $f ; done > a
```